# How do I get a reference to a telerik:GridTemplateColumn from a child control?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Simplified code from page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" etc... %>
<%@ Register src="~/controls/RequiredField.ascx" tagname="rf" tagprefix="custom" %>

<telerik:RadGrid runat="server">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
                <ItemTemplate><%#Eval("Name")%></ItemTemplate>                    
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="NewName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name")%>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <custom:rf runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

In my control, I want to check if the parent is an `EditItemTemplate` and then set a property of the `telerik:GridTemplateColumn`. For example:

```
public partial class controls_RequiredField : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent is Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem.EditFormTableCell)
        {
            // how do I get a reference to 'Telerik.Web.UI.GridTemplateColumn' (or any other object that lets me set the header text)
            ((Telerik.Web.UI.GridTemplateColumn)this.Parent.Parent).EditFormHeaderTextFormat = "{0}:" + RequiredText.Text;
            RequiredText.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is the code I'm currently using that works:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.Parent is GridEditFormItem.EditFormTableCell)
    {
        GridEditFormItem.EditFormTableCell parentCell = (GridEditFormItem.EditFormTableCell)this.Parent;
        string col = parentCell.ColumnName;
        // ridiculous:
        Control parentFormItem = this.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
        if (parentFormItem is GridItem)
        {
            GridItem gi = (GridItem)parentFormItem;
            GridColumn parentColumn = gi.OwnerTableView.Columns.FindByUniqueNameSafe(col);
            if (parentColumn != null)
            {
                parentColumn.EditFormHeaderTextFormat = "{0}:" + RequiredText.Text;
                RequiredText.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But having to cycle up through all those `.Parent`s makes me uneasy.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the [`telerik:RadGrid`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/t_telerik_web_ui_radgrid.html) but it is pretty similar to the MS GridView, so I was able to test your issue using [`asp:GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) (both inherit from [CompositeDataBoundControl Class (System.Web.UI.WebControls)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.compositedataboundcontrol.aspx))

since your custom control is located in the `EditItemTemplate` your `RequiredField` control's `Page_Load` event will not fire until the `RadGrid` switches to edit mode so you should be able to drop the `if (this.Parent is...)` check as you'll know the grid is in edit mode.

So with the custom control's page load indicating the grid is in edit mode you can set the `HeaderText` of the `GridTemplateColumn` by doing something like:

```
if (typeof(DataControlFieldCell) == Parent.GetType())
{
    ((DataControlFieldCell)this.Parent).ContainingField.HeaderText = "Your Custom Heading"; // Or += if appending
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a bit. I've updated my question's code with the progress I've made. `this.Parent is Telerik.Web.UI.GridEditFormItem.EditFormTableCell` so using `DataControlFieldCell` won't work in this case.